# pandas time series index.day attribute error

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, time-series

I am trying to get the day, month, year, or quarter (anything) by using the time series.  But I keep receiving the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'day'

I am using v14 for pandas
I've looked at [the cookbook tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/Chapter%204%20-%20Find%20out%20on%20which%20weekday%20people%20bike%20the%20most%20with%20groupby%20and%20aggregate.ipynb):

```
scd = raw_data[['SCD_LV_YMD']]

     SCD_LV_YMD
0    2000-09-23
1    1999-10-23
2    1999-10-23
3    1989-04-12
4    1989-04-12
5    1989-05-30
6    1989-05-30
7    1989-05-30
8    1996-01-14
9    1996-01-14
```

scd.index will give me the following:

```
In [85]:

scd.index
Out[85]:
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, ...], dtype='int64')
```

but when I try to reference the day it gives me an error

```
In [98]:scd.index.day
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-718bfa312e31> in <module>()
----> 1 scd.index.day[:-1]

AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'day'
```

I brought in the data using pd.read.csv and parsed the dates.

They originally came in looking like 19891023

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\davidlopez\Desktop\Folders\Standard Reports\HR Reports\ERI RNO DATA\DAVEPHIS\\davephis\davefy14.txt',
                       names=[
                                'NM_EMP_LST',
                                'NM_EMP_FST',
                                'NAT_ACTN_1_3',
                                'NAT_ACTN_2_3',
                                'ACTN_DT',
                                'ACTN_YMD',
                                'TYPE_APNT',
                                'ORG_LEV2',
                                'ORG_LEV3',
                                'ORG_LEV4',
                                'ORG_LEV5',
                                'MR_NBR',
                                'POS_OFF_TTL',
                                'APNT_NA_ACTN',
                                'APNT_AUTH_1',
                                'APNT_YMD',
                                'SCD_CSR_YMD',
                                'SCD_LV_YMD',
                                'SSNO',
                                'TENURE_GROUP'], parse_dates=['ACTN_DT','ACTN_YMD','APNT_YMD','SCD_CSR_YMD','SCD_LV_YMD'])
```

Comment: Your index is of dtype `Int64` not a `datetime` or `timestamp`, please show how you loaded the data and where the data came from, the notebook you linked to show's different code

Comment: thanks for responding.  Hopefully my edits above will help clarify.

Comment: I don't see where you set the index to a date time like column, you either access an existing column's day attribute or set one of these columns as your index and then access it's day attribute

Comment: The index is just row numbers - the dates are in the data itself.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I would like to get a month, day of week, etc from the date.  I was reading the cookbook referenced above and it explained using index.day, index.weekday was the way to do it.

Comment: `df.index.day` will **only** work if your index has datetime values (it tries to get the 'day' component of the index, not of some column). But, as explained in the comments above, you *don't* have that but an index with integer values. What you can do is: `pd.DatetimeIndex(raw_data['SCD_LV_YMD']).day`

Comment: Beautiful Joris, that was the fix that I needed!  Thanks to all for input.  I learned from all.

Comment: It worked for me too